# Norm equivalence between inf-norm and polynomial coefficients

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Assume I have a normalised sequence of polynomials $(p_i)_{i = 0}^\infty$ ($\|p_i\|_\infty = 1$ for all $i = 0,1,\ldots$) such that $\mathcal{P}_n = \mathrm{span}\{p_0, \ldots, p_n\}$ for all $n = 0,1, \ldots$, and that 
$$
f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^n c_i \, p_i(x).
$$ 
It is straightforward to show
$$
\|f\|_\infty \leq \|c\|_1.
$$
Is it also possible to get a bound in the opposite direction, i.e. some result of the form 
$$
\|c\|_1 \leq C \, \|f\|_\infty?
$$
I am particularly interested in the case of $p_i(x) = C \, x^i$ being the monomial basis, where here $C$ is the normalising factor to ensure $\|p_i\|_\infty = 1$. Also, I don't really need the 1-norm in the coefficient space, any other norm such that the space of infinite sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ is complete would do as well.

Comment: Your summation in $f$ is to $\infty$ which is outside the span $\cal{P}_n$. Typo?

Comment: @A.G. From context it is clear that the upper bound of the sum should be $n$, so I edited it.

Comment: That wasn't a typo. The point is that $f$ may *not* be a polynomial, but can be approximated using polynomials (think of Taylor series, or polynomial approximation). I edited the question to point this out more clearly (I hope).

Comment: If this inequality were true it would mean that the operator $f\mapsto c$ could be extended to a continuous operator $L_\infty\to \ell_1$, and any $f\in L_\infty$ would be represented by the absolutely convergent series, in particular, were continuous. But it is not true.

Comment: @A.G. Thanks for this hint! Can I save the situation if I assume $f$ to be analytic?

Comment: I do not think so. You would need to change the norm too, inf-norm is too weak. For example, if we consider the trigonometric polynomials instead (which are nicer in a way), then the best inclusion for the Wiener algebra (as far as I know) is $\text{Lip}_\alpha(\Bbb{T})$ with $\alpha>1/2$ (see Theorem 4, page 4 [here](http://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/wieneralgebra.pdf)).

Comment: And what if I impose additional constraints on the $p_i$ *and* $f$? For example, if I fix the domain of $f$ to be $[-1,1]$, the $p_i$ to be the Chebyshev polynomials and $f$ to be analytic on some open domain containing $[-1,1]$, then I get that the coefficients decay exponentially and are hence summable. In fact, I would be perfectly happy if one could only generalise this statement to arbitrary domains in the complex plane.